# Tomcat and cacerts

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl

I have a third party certificate installed in my `%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts` file. I have written a local test program to test that this is imported well and I receive the reply as expected.

When running the program from tomcat I receive an error

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: So Tomcat isn't  using that file, or the certificate received isn't in that file.

Comment: certificate is def in the file. Confirmed by running `"%JAVA_HOME%/bin/keytool" -list -keystore "%JAVA_HOME%/jre/lib/security/cacerts" -v` and my running a test java program without tomcat which worked.